# GridBagLayout columnwidths,rowHeights, columnWeights and rowWeights

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I tried to learn using gridbaglayout but the thing is, I still do not understand what does the new int[]{} means for .columnwidths and .rowHeights and new double[]{} for .columnWeights and .rowWeights after changing the codes. Can anyone give an example and explain how it works? Like how do I determine the numbers to set in the new int{} and new double[]{}

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
    import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;

    public class UI extends JPanel {

        private JPanel clickMePanel,panel_1,panel_2;
        private JButton button;

        public UI() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
            gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
            gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
            gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
            gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
            setLayout(gridBagLayout);

            clickMePanel = new JPanel();

            clickMePanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            GridBagConstraints gbcClickMePanel = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbcClickMePanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbcClickMePanel.gridx = 0;
            gbcClickMePanel.gridy = 0;
            add(clickMePanel, gbcClickMePanel);
            GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
            gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[]{0,0};
            gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{0,0};
            gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
            gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
            clickMePanel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

            button = new JButton("button");
            GridBagConstraints gbcBtn = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbcBtn.gridx = 0;
            gbcBtn.gridy = 0;
            clickMePanel.add(button, gbcBtn);

        }

        public static void main(String args[]){
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.getContentPane().add(new UI());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setSize(600, 400);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"Can anyone give an example and explain how it works?"*  SO is not a tutorial site, but a Q&A site where it is best to ask a specific (and not too broad) question.  I suggest instead plugging 'how to use X' in your favorite search engine, where X in this case is 'GridBagLayout'.  Voting to close.

Comment: Each element in the array is a column or row index (cell). Oh and 15 years, I've never used it this way ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer so I am using the gridbaglayout wrongly?

Comment: I wouldn't say you're using it wrong, just that I've never used it that way, instead I use `GridBagConstraints` to determine the individual constraints for each component. To me, they are easier to use and manage, but that's me. See [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Comment: 1. I'm using array of JLabels  in the 1st. row (GBC are strictly about column/s), then is matrix created, rest of GUI is about column and row, == MigLayout or TableLayout 2. plus one for SSCCE/MCVE, 3. but voting to close too